# Android layout that the components inside it can be moved to the new line when no width space

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the Android layout that the components inside it can be moved to the new line if there is no more width space at the current line?

Comment: I believe there is no such layout available. But its a good question.

Comment: There is no chance for that purpose designed gridview as per the my best